# Weird login behavior in tty1-6

Tags: command-line, 18.04, login, tty, virtual-console

I have a very peculiar problem with my ubuntu 18.04 LTS. I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to go to tty1 as always. And there is the classic screen that you have to login as always. But when I try to login this happens:

I put my username and click enter. Then the password field shows up but the terminal clicks return automatically before me being able to enter my password. Then of course it asks for password again, and then terminal clicks return again. Then the whole login thing resets and asks for username again but terminal keeps clicking return and at some point it completely resets and it stops as if I had just pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.

Anyone have any clues?

Thanks